# OData Referencing Requests in a Change Set

Tags: odata

I have batch request to update data. 
Data Is:

```
Item : {   
 id : int,   
 name : string,    
 RefItem : {
    int : id,
    name : string   }
}
```

I need

1. Create Item
2. Update RefItem reference for this newly created Item, in the same batch. (Suppose RefItems(1) already exists in data set)

According to OData spec:

--batch_1872-f36a-7ce8

Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=changeset_8c16-9ba3-2260

--changeset_8c16-9ba3-2260

Content-Type: application/http

Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

PUT $1/$links/ItemRef HTTP/1.1

Content-ID: 2

Accept: application/atomsvc+xml;q=0.8, application/json;q=0.5, */*;q=0.1

DataServiceVersion: 1.0

Content-Type: application/json

{"uri":"ItemRefs(1)"}

--changeset_8c16-9ba3-2260

Content-Type: application/http

Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

POST Products HTTP/1.1

Content-ID: 1

Accept: application/atomsvc+xml;q=0.8, application/json;q=0.5, */*;q=0.1

DataServiceVersion: 1.0

Content-Type: application/json

{"id":-1,"name":"seven"}

--changeset_8c16-9ba3-2260--

--batch_1872-f36a-7ce8--

I suppose it should work, but I have response error :

--batchresponse_4febeba8-dd43-4040-9fdb-866afde5304e
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=changesetresponse_424dbf12-fa9a-4a59-8284-963fa0fa7b77

--changesetresponse_424dbf12-fa9a-4a59-8284-963fa0fa7b77
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-ID: 2
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
DataServiceVersion: 1.0;
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8

{"d":{"error":{"code":"","message":{"lang":"ru-RU","value":"An error occurred while processing this request."}}}}
--changesetresponse_424dbf12-fa9a-4a59-...

Can somebody tell me where I'm wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The batch request is processed as a stream. So you can only refer to content ID which was already seen. The above sample refers to content ID 1 before the request operation with that content ID. That is not valid.

You need to first create the new instance (POST) and then add a reference to it via the $links URL.